# sqlplus variable value is not accepting in EOF block in shell

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix

I am unable to give input to the variable "y" written in below code. Can any one help us Please. 
Code :

```
#!/bin/bash
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -s abcd/passabcd <<EOF
declare
res varchar2(9) := '&y';
begin
insert into abc values(10);
if res in ('commit;')
then
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'commit;';
elsif res in ('rollback;')
then
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'rollback;';
else
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enter Correct Input');
end if;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Error msg ' ||  substr(sqlerrm,1,200));
end;
/
EOF
```

if i run this, below is the screen. automatically i am getting sp2-0546 error without entering any input.

```
[oracle@ssmz861 ~]$ ./mm.sh
Enter value for y:SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.
[oracle@ssmz861 ~]$
```

here is the scenario: I have a `pl/sql` code i need to give to `sqlplus` to execute in following manner like `<EOF .....EOF.` in that one i have to see the output of one query and decide whether need to commit or rollback by giving input.

thanks in advance
Siva

Comment: Your `stdin` is redirected. Why would the process expect you to enter anything on the terminal, unless there is explicit code in the application to read from `tty`?

Comment: Thank you Boss. May i know how to ask user to enter either commit or roll back. and entered command should execute on Same session. this we are trying in One of Production database.                                                             Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you Boss. May i know how control will ask user to enter either commit or roll back. and entered command should execute on Same session. this we are trying in One of Production database.                                                             Thanks in advance

Comment: See if `sqlplus` command accepts these commands as a file, instead of `stdin`. (e.g. `bash < file` and `bash file` will both execute the script, but in a different way. Your current code resembles second case.) Or try [`expect`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/expect/).

Comment: Thank you Boss, The scenario is, EOF contains 600 lines of pl/sql code. user needs to commit. if results of update and insert statements are correct. Other wise user has to roll back it. and that too i must be in same session to either commit or rollback. i am just trying to give input by typing "Commit;" this should go and execute in same session if results are perfect. if results are suspicious, user needs to rollback the transcation by typing "Rollback;". Please help me here. please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Try using `expect`. `expect` has provision to take input from the user and automating entering the text at the prompt.